# Vue.js hot reload over ..apache?

Tags: vue.js

So my backend is PHP based (processwire), served by trusty old MAMP (`localhost:8888/mysite`). I'd like to serve my vue.js app from the same server, as well.

`npm run dev` starts a local server on `localhost:8080`, that works for doing the front end stuff, hot reloading and all.

With `npm run build` i can build my app so it can be served from MAMP.

But how can I get hot reloading working over MAMP so I can keep developing through apache (using `localhost:8888/mysite`)? Is this possible?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried but couldn't get hot loading to work by proxying through Apache. The other way around wasn't so hard, in webpack.config.js:

```
proxy: {
      '/mysite/api/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8888',
        secure: false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the dev-server from webpack to get it running.

But you could use apache as proxy for it. Probably this could work (assume Apache an webpack-dev-server runs on `localhost:8080`

```
ProxyPass        /mysite http://localhost:8080/mysite
ProxyPassReverse /mysite http://localhost:8080/mysite
```

So the tricky Part is to tell Webpack to server under `/mysite`. That depends an your config. If you come from the Vue webpack template (generate with vue-cli) you have `assetsPublicPath` in your `/config/index.js`

Comment: ..You mean using dev-server as proxy for apache? Like this? http://nikolay.rocks/2016-01-13-connect-webpack-to-backend

Comment: I think you want the way around. Use Apache to proxy /mysite to webpack?
In my devtools I saw http://localhost:8080/__webpack_hmr is from type eventsource so you wouldnt need sockets at all.

I'll edit my answer ...